# probability of a random walk visit 0 k times before reaching N

Tags: probability

Question 3.11.23(probability theory and random processes by Grimmett): Consider a symmetric random walk with an absorbing barrier at $N$ and a reflecting barrier at $0$(so that , when the particle is at $0$, it moves to $1$ at the next step). Let $a_k(j)$ be the probability that the particle, having started at $k$, visits $0$ exactly $j$ times before being absorbed at $N$. We make the convention that, if $k=0$, then the starting point counts as one visit. What is $a_k(j)$?

Ok so $a_k(j)=pa_{k+1}(j)+qa_{k-1}(j)$, $a_N(j)=0,a_0(j)=a_1(j-1)=pa_2(j-1)+qa_1(j-2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it would be easier to first define $b_k(j)$ as the probability that a particle starting at $k$ visits $0$ *at least* $j$ times before visiting $N.$

From this, we can see that $$a_k(j) = b_k(j) - b_k(j+1) \\ b_k(j) = b_k(1) \cdot b_1(j-1) = b_k(1)\cdot b_1(1)^{j-1}$$
When evaluating $b_k(1),$ we can think of both $0$ and $N$ as absorbing states.  Since $$b_0(1) = 1, \quad b_N(1) = 0, \\ 1 \leq k \leq N-1 \implies b_k(1) = \frac{1}{2}b_{k-1}(1) + \frac{1}{2}b_{k+1}(1)$$
we can solve for $b_k(1) = 1 - \frac{k}{N}.$

Putting it together,
$$b_k(j) = b_k(1) \cdot b_1(1)^{j-1} = \left(1-\frac{k}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{j-1} \\ a_k(j) = b_k(j) - b_k(j+1) = \left(1-\frac{k}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{j-1}\left( \frac{1}{N}\right)$$

Comment: thank you sir, Can you also explain on how you would solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: Could you please explain the equation $b_k(j)=b_k(1)b_1(j-1)$? And why is it better to work with probabilities of _at least_ instead as the exact ones?

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I guess you mean visiting 0, as the original question asks. Then, wouldn't it be $b_k(j)=b_k(1)b_0(j-1)$? It wouldn't affect the final result, since $b_0(1)=1$. I see now that for $a_k(j)$ you need to look at the future to avoid arriving to the origin in future steps beyond the number j. Let me add: if there weren't a reflecting barrier at 0, the equations would be the same, right?

Comment: @David Right.  I meant visits to 0 in my comment.  For some reason I misread both the question and my answer... I'm going to rewrite those comments with that fixed, because it'll help answer your other questions.

Comment: @David At a high level, the statement just says that in order to start at $k$ and visit $0$ at least $j$ times, the random walk must visit $0$ the first time, at which point it necessarily moves to $1$ next, and then starting from $1$ it must visit $0$ at least $j-1$ more times.  (here we use the Markov property of the random walk)

Comment: This equation is actually why it's easier to work with the $b_k(j)$ instead of the $a_k(j)$, as something like $b_k(1)$ measures "a random walk that starts at $k$ visits $0$ before $N$.  Given any realization of the random walk, we can tell whether it's in this event or not as soon as it visits either $0$ or $N$.  Compare this to $a_k(1)$, where a realization that visits $0$ before $N$ may still not be in the associated event, and telling whether it is requires looking at its "future"

Comment: With that in mind, we can't use the correction you've given because both $a_k(j)$ and $b_k(j)$ are defined by counting the starting position as a visit when $k=0$.  Instead, we can use $$b_k(j) = b_k(1) b_0(j) = b_k(1) b_1(j-1).$$ And if there weren't a reflecting barrier at $0$, the equations would still be the same, but you would need to separately prove that a symmetric simple random walk satisfies $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1 \text{ for some } n>0 | X_0 = 0) = 1$ in order for the analysis to work.

Comment: @David And now that I've had _another_ day to think on it, I have to walk back my last statement, as I was, once again, mixing up $0$ and $1$ in my last comment.  If there weren't a reflecting barrier at $0$, this **would** change the equations because we would have to account for visits to $0$ from $-1$ (i.e. we'd have to subtract them).  If instead there were a reflecting barrier at $0$ and we were counting visits to $1$, then we could ignore the reflecting barrier if we wanted.

Comment: Thx, Brian. My doubt was that if we don't have the barrier at 0, we begin at k (let's say k>0), then the prob of visiting 0 j times before N cannot be $b_k(j)=b_k(1)b_1(j-1)+b_k(-1)b_{-1}(j-1)$ because we overcount, right? We could do the prob of arriving to 0 for the first time using $c_k=pc_{k+1}+qc_{k-1}$, then, how could we relate it to the probability of arriving to 0 for the jth time before reaching N?

Comment: @David At this point we are sufficiently far from the original question and answer that you should make a new question if you want an answer.